# Unable To Change The Image Resource Of Image Button In A Grid View

Tags: android, gridview, android-imagebutton, sparse-array

The `GridView` in my app consists of multiple `ImageButtons`. When an `ImageButton` is tapped, the image resource of that ImageButton will change.

This is the int array of the image resource ids when an `ImageButton` is not tapped.

```
private final int mineIcons[] = 
{
    R.drawable.habit,
    R.drawable.story,
    R.drawable.submenu_voice_message,
    R.drawable.study,
    R.drawable.guess,
    R.drawable.poem,
    R.drawable.add
};
```

This is the int array of the image resource ids when an `ImageButton` is tapped.

```
private final int mineIconsSelected[] = 
{
    R.drawable.habit_selected,
    R.drawable.story_selected,
    R.drawable.submenu_voice_message_selected,
    R.drawable.study_selected,
    R.drawable.guess_selected,
    R.drawable.poem_selected,
    R.drawable.add
};
```

When this activity is loaded, I want that the first `ImageButton` in the `GridView` is in state of "tapped". So I set this int array of image resource ids for default image resource of the `ImageButtons` when the `ImageButtons` are loaded.

```
private final int mineIconsDefault[] = 
{
    R.drawable.habit_selected,
    R.drawable.story,
    R.drawable.submenu_voice_message,
    R.drawable.study,
    R.drawable.guess,
    R.drawable.poem,
    R.drawable.add
};
```

This is the complete code of the `Fragment`

public class MineFragment extends Fragment
{
    private final static String LOG_TAG = "MineFragment";

```
private final int mineIcons[] = 
{
    R.drawable.habit,
    R.drawable.story,
    R.drawable.submenu_voice_message,
    R.drawable.study,
    R.drawable.guess,
    R.drawable.poem,
    R.drawable.add
};

private final int mineIconsSelected[] = 
{
    R.drawable.habit_selected,
    R.drawable.story_selected,
    R.drawable.submenu_voice_message_selected,
    R.drawable.study_selected,
    R.drawable.guess_selected,
    R.drawable.poem_selected,
    R.drawable.add
};

private SparseArray<ImageButton> submenuIconArray = new SparseArray<ImageButton>();
private SubMenuListAdapter submenuListAdapter = new SubMenuListAdapter();
private MineListAdapter mineListAdapter = new MineListAdapter();

private GridView gvSubmenu;
private ListView lvMine;

private int selectedItemNumber = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mine, container, false);
    init(view);

    return view;
}

private void init(View view)
{
    lvMine = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv_mine);
    lvMine.setAdapter(mineListAdapter);

    gvSubmenu = (GridView)getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content).findViewById(R.id.gv_submenu);
    gvSubmenu.setAdapter(submenuListAdapter);
}

public void showSubmenu()
{
    if(gvSubmenu != null)
    {
        gvSubmenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public void hideSubmenu()
{
    if(gvSubmenu != null)
    {
        gvSubmenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private class SubMenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{       
    private final int mineIconsDefault[] = 
    {
        R.drawable.habit_selected,
        R.drawable.story,
        R.drawable.submenu_voice_message,
        R.drawable.study,
        R.drawable.guess,
        R.drawable.poem,
        R.drawable.add
    };

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return mineIconsDefault.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return mineIconsDefault[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup root) 
    {
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_submenu, root, false);
        }

        ImageButton ibSubmenuIcon = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ib_item_submenu_icon);
        ibSubmenuIcon.setImageResource(mineIconsDefault[position]);
        ibSubmenuIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {   
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                submenuIconArray.get(selectedItemNumber).setImageResource(mineIcons[selectedItemNumber]);
                submenuIconArray.get(position).setImageResource(mineIconsSelected[position]);

                selectedItemNumber = position;
            }
        });

        submenuIconArray.append(position, ibSubmenuIcon);

        return convertView;
    }
}

private class MineListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    //temp 
    private String[] tempListItems = {"item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5"};

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return tempListItems.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) 
    {
        return tempListItems[arg0];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup root) 
    {
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout_1, root, false);
        }

        ImageView ivItemIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_item_icon);
        TextView tvItemLabel = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_label);

        tvItemLabel.setText(tempListItems[position]);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

}

I use `SparseArray` to store each `ImageButton` loaded in the `GridView` so that later when I have to change the image resource of an `ImageButton`, I will just have to get that `ImageButton` from the `SparseArray` and then set its image resource to the corresponding one in the `mineIconsSelected` int array. Before doing that I will make sure that the image resource of the `ImageButton` I previously tapped will be set to the corresponding one in the `mineIcons` int array.

Now, the strange problem comes in.

I was able to successfully change the image resource of any `ImageButton` stored in the `SparseArray` upon tapping, **EXCEPT** the **FIRST** one. No matter how many times I check my code, make Logs, I can't find where the problem is.

Please help me. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd strongly suggest simplifying your code first. After doing so your problem will either go away or be much easier to debug. It will be a bit tedious upfront since you have so many buttons, but it will make your code a lot more manageable. 
Create a simple selector drawable file for each button. i.e. for the habit button:
habit_selector.xml (place in drawable folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/habit" android:android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/habit_selected"/>
</selector>
```

Then set it on your button:

```
private final int mineIconSelectors[] = 
{
    R.drawable.habit_selector,
    R.drawable.story_selector,
    R.drawable.submenu_voice_message_selector,
    ...
}

    ...
    ImageButton ibSubmenuIcon = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ib_item_submenu_icon);
    ibSubmenuIcon.setBackground(mineIconSelectors[position]);
```

Thus when the button is selected, Android will automatically switch the drawable asset for you.

Comment: A longer explanation here: http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2014/03/android-button-selector-tutorial-with.html#.VbGu6vlVhBc

Comment: I tried this before. It's not working. Not even a single button would change its background.

Comment: I even tried to separate that button, put it in an ImageButton object. and specifically change only that button, still no game.

Comment: Simplify a bit more, use Button instead of ImageButton and make sure to use setBackground() NOT setImageResource()

Comment: I tried that too. I tried both ImageView and Button but still not working.